# Rename PDFs while "open", like mp3tag

Tags: pdf, filenames

I have 700 PDFs and I want to rename the file itself to sort them out first (there are mostly journal articles so metadata hard to find).

Is there a program that I can look at the PDF and then rename it?

Comment: What OS?  Gratis or commercial software?  Help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

In windows 10 if you turn on the preview pane of file explorer, (I am sure that there are equivelenets in other OSes) you can see the content and rename the file at the same time.
[image]